# FullCalendar 5 - How do I get the colour of each event?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am setting a specific event's colour in FullCalendar 5 with (each event can have a different colour):

```
color: 'Red',
```

I am then trying to retrieve the specific event's colour with:

```
eventClick: function(info) {
    var eventObj = info.event;
    $('#updateColour').val(eventObj.color);
}
```

However, "eventObj.color" is undefined. How do I get the colour of each event?

Comment: I can confirm I see the same with [a simple JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/h3zkn6xf/).  The specified `color` is used (even non-standard capitalised colours like `Red`), but is not available as readable property.  Note that `color` is not actually *listed* as a property in [the `eventObject` docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object), even though it is described on [the `eventColor` page](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventColor); also note that `backgroundColor` *is* accessible, even if not specified, and comes from `color`. Maybe you can just use `backgroundColor`?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I have changed the "color" to "backgroundColor" and this works. Please add this as your answer so I can upvote and accept. Also, this only gives a coloured dot next to the event when it has a start and end time. Is there a way to have a background colour for events that have a start and end time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the problem you're seeing in the simple snippet below.  It looks like you've bumped into a bug, or something undocumented, or maybe just a bug in the documentation.

The `eventColor` (a whole-calendar-level property) [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventColor) says:

> This option can be overridden  ... on a per-event basis with the `color` Event Object option.

But clicking through to [the linked `eventObject` docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object), there is no such `color` option listed.  Instead there are `backgroundColor` and `borderColor` properties.

In the snippet I tried both specifying an event `color`, and reading it.  Setting works - the event is drawn with the specified colour on the calendar.  But just as you found, reading it fails, `color` is undefined.

Setting and reading `backgroundColor` and `borderColor` works fine, and by specifying both `color` and `backgroundColor` on a single event, it seems `color` is shorthand for setting both `backgroundColor` and `borderColor` (see Events 2 and 3 in the snippet).

So there's a workaround: we can *set* `color`, which transparently sets `backgroundColor`, which we can then *read*.  See the snippet for a demo.

##### Update:

Regarding your extra question in the comments:

> Also, this only gives a coloured dot next to the event when it has a start and end time. Is there a way to have a background colour for events that have a start and end time?

I haven't used it but I searched and came across [the `eventDisplay` property](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDisplay), which seems to be what you're after.  I updated the snippet and specified the `block` option, which changes an event with start and end times from a list-item to a block, just like all day events - see Event 4.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    initialDate: '2021-11-07',
    eventDisplay: 'block',
    events: [{
        title: 'Event 1',
        start: '2021-11-01',
        color: 'Red',
      },
      {
        title: 'Event 2',
        start: '2021-11-02',
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        color: 'red'
      },
      {
        title: 'Event 3',
        start: '2021-11-03',
        color: 'red',
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
      },
      {
        title: 'Event 4',
        start: "2021-11-04T10:00:00-08:00",
        end: "2021-11-04T11:30:00-08:00",
        color: 'orange',
      },
    ],
    eventClick: function(info) {
      alert('color: ' + info.event.color + '; backgroundColor: ' + info.event.backgroundColor);
    }
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```html
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.1/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.10.1/main.min.js'></script>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```